# Find the number of pages in a PDF using PHP

Tags: php

I have researched this for a few days now and finally found something that seemed to work, but I am getting the wrong result. I need to count the number of pages in a PDF file on a remote server.  My code opens the PDF, but it's not finding the correct number of pages and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code so far:

```
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('Awss3', null, 'S3');
    $CI->load->library('Pdflib');
    $data = $CI->S3->readFile('uploads/225572/filename.pdf', false, 'bucket-name');
    $needle = 'Page';
    $positions = array();
    $lastPos = 0;
    while (($lastPos = strpos($data, $needle, $lastPos))!==false) {
        $positions[] = $lastPos;
        $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
    }
    echo count($positions);
    foreach ($positions as $value) {
        echo $value . '<br />';
    }
    $test = strpos($data, 'Page');
```

If I echo out the $data, I get lots of symbols, etc. and some words, but the $test comes out to 0 when it should be 16. Does it depend on the type of PDF or do I need to decode it or something like that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. We don't know what `get_instance()` is doing, what type the `load` property is, what the arguments for the `library()` method mean, what `S3` is and what `readFile()` is returning. You need most likely a PDF library which you fill with the PDF file, that can give you the number of pages according to the API of the PDF library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest of all is using ImageMagick
here is a sample code

```
 $image = new Imagick();
 $image->pingImage('myPdfFile.pdf');
 echo $image->getNumberImages();
```

otherwise you can also use PDF libraries like MPDF or TCPDF for PHP

Comment: thank you for responding. I would prefer not to have to download anything else to make this work. Do you know if there is a way to make my existing code work without downloading Imagick?